# How/Why did Feynman relate the element of Hamiltonian matrix $H_{12}$ to the amplitude to go from $|1\rangle$ to $| 2\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution

> Our problem, then, is to understand the matrix $U(t_2,t_1)$ for an infinitesimal time interval—for $t_2=t_1+Δt$. We ask ourselves this: If we have a state $ϕ$ now, what does the state look like an infinitesimal time $Δt$ later? Let’s see how we write that out. Call the state at the time t, $\ket{ψ(t)}$ (we show the time dependence of $ψ$ to be perfectly clear that we mean the condition at the time $t$). Now we ask the question: What is the condition after the small interval of time $Δt$ later? The answer is $
> \newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left\langle #1 | #2 \right\rangle}
> \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right\rangle} 
> \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right|} 
> \newcommand{\biik}[3]{\left\langle #1 | #2| #3\right\rangle}
> $
>   $$\ket{ψ(t+Δt)}=U(t+Δt,t)\ket{ψ(t)}.$$ We can also resolve the $\ket{ψ(t)}$ into base states and write $$\bk{i}{ψ(t+Δt)}=\sum_j \biik{i}{U(t+Δt,t)}{j} \bk{j}{ψ(t)}.$$Each amplitude at $(t+Δt)$ is proportional to all of the other amplitudes at $t$ multiplied by a set of coefficients. Let’s call the $U$-matrix $U_{ij}$, by which we mean
>   $$U_{ij}=\biik{i}{U}{j}.$$
>   Then we can write $$C_i(t+Δt)=\sum_j U_{ij}(t+Δt,t)C_j(t).$$This, then, is how the dynamics of quantum mechanics is going to look.
>   [..] if $Δt$ goes to zero, nothing can happen—we should get just the original state. So, $U_{ii}→1$ and $U_{ij}→0$, if $i≠j$. In other words, $U_{ij}→δ_{ij}$ for $Δt→0.$ Also, we can suppose that for small $Δt$, each of the coefficients $U_{ij}$ should differ from $δ_{ij}$ by amounts proportional to $Δt$; so we can write
>   $$U_{ij}=δ_{ij}+K_{ij}Δt.$$
>   However, it is usual to take the factor $(−i/ℏ)$ out of the coefficients $K_{ij}$, for historical and other reasons; we prefer to write
>   $$U_{ij}(t+Δt,t)=δ_{ij}−\frac{i}{ℏ} H_{ij}(t)Δt.$$The terms $H_{ij}$ are just the **derivatives** with respect to $t_2$ of the coefficients $U_{ij}(t_2,t_1)$, evaluated at $t_2=t_1=t.$
>   Using this form for $U$, we have
>   $$C_i(t+Δt)=\sum_j \left[δ_{ij}−\frac{i}{ℏ}H_{ij}(t)Δt\right]Cj(t).$$
>   Taking the sum over the $δ_{ij}$ term, we get just $C_i(t)$, which we can put on the other side of the equation. Then dividing by $Δt$, we have what we recognize as a derivative
>   $$C_i(t+Δt)−Ci(t)Δt=−\frac{i}{ℏ}\sum_j H_{ij}(t)Cj(t)$$
>   or $$iℏ\frac{dC_i(t)}{dt}= \sum_j H_{ij}(t)Cj(t).$$

This is how Feynman defined $H_{ij}$ as the derivative of $U_{ij}$. This is the ${ij}^\text{th}$ element of Hamiltonian matrix. Then he wrote rather abruptly,

> The coefficients $H_{ij}$ are called the Hamiltonian matrix or, for short, just the Hamiltonian. (How Hamilton, who worked in the 1830s, got his name on a quantum mechanical matrix is a tale of history.) It would be much better called the **energy matrix**, for reasons that will become apparent as we work with it. So the problem is: Know your Hamiltonian!

So, $H_{ij}$ which is the *time-derivative* of $U_{ij}$ matrix is related to the energy of the system.

But after two chapters, he from nowhere mentioned that $H_{ij}$ is the *amplitude* to go from $\ket 1$ to $\ket 2$. As

> A positively ionized hydrogen molecule consists of two protons with one electron worming its way around them. If the two protons are very far apart, what states would we expect for this system? The answer is pretty clear: The electron will stay close to one proton and form a hydrogen atom in its lowest state, and the other proton will remain alone as a positive ion. So, if the two protons are far apart, we can visualize one physical state in which the electron is “attached” to one of the protons. There is, clearly, another state symmetric to that one in which the electron is near the other proton, and the first proton is the one that is an ion. We will take these two as our base states, and we’ll call them $\ket{1}$ and $\ket{2}.$ There is some small amplitude for the electron to move from one proton to the other. As a first approximation, then, each of our base states $\ket{1}$ and $\ket{2}$ will have the energy $E_0$, which is just the energy of one hydrogen atom plus one proton. We can take that the Hamiltonian matrix elements $H_{11}$ and $H_{22}$ are both approximately equal to $E_0.$ The other **matrix elements $H_{12}$ and $H_{21}$, which are the amplitudes for the electron to go back and forth, we will again write as $−A$.**

I'm not understanding this; $H_{12}$ & $H_{21}$ are the time-derivatives of $U_{12}\;\&\;U_{21}$ respectively. How can they be the *amplitude* to go from $\ket 1$ to $\ket 2$? After all, it is related to Kronecker delta $\delta{ij}$ or if under time-evolution, then related to $U_{ij}$. $U_{ij}$ should be the *amplitudes for the electron to go back and forth* that is the amplitude for the hydrogen ion to go from $\ket 1$ to $\ket 2$ or vice-versa. So, why did Feynman wrote $H_{ij}$ as the amplitude instead of $U_{ij}$ after all, $H_{ij}$ is the time-derivative of $U_{ij}$ & not any amplitude to go from $\ket 1$ to $\ket 2$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left\langle #1 | #2 \right\rangle}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right\rangle} 
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right|} 
\newcommand{\biik}[3]{\left\langle #1 | #2| #3\right\rangle}
$To first order, we can write $\hat U(\delta t)=1-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat H\delta t$. Then if we start in state $\ket{1}$, our amplitude on state $\ket{2}$ is $\bra{2}\hat U(\delta t)\ket{1}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\delta t\bra{2}\hat H\ket{1}$. So we see that the instantaneous transition rate to go from $\ket{1}$ to $\ket{2}$ is (up to factors of $\hbar$) $\bra{2}\hat H\ket{1}$, as desired.